# Deleting a result during WHILE statement

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Rather than showing you all the ways I tried to do it and got it wrong, I will just give you the code here and then ask the question below it...

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect($db_server_name, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$con) {
    echo "0";
}
mysql_select_db("" . $db_database_name . "", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sched_posts
WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $post_id      = $row['ID'];
    $post_year    = $row['post_year'];
    $post_month   = $row['post_month'];
    $post_day     = $row['post_day'];
    $post_hour    = $row['post_hour'];
    $post_minute  = $row['post_minute'];
    $post_privacy = $row['post_privacy'];
    $post_message = $row['post_message'];

    $current_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i');
    $sched_format      = "$post_year-$post_month-$post_day $post_hour:$post_minute";
    echo "$current_date_time";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "$sched_format";
    echo "<br>";
    if ($current_date_time >= $sched_format) {
        $attachment = array(
            'message' => '' . $post_message . '',
            'name' => 'Title',
            'source' => 'http://www.youtube.com/e/2raioEC7Hms',
            'privacy' => array(
                'value' => '' . $post_privacy . ''
            ),
            'caption' => "Caption",
            'link' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/something/',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent suscipit pharetra mauris in fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'picture' => 'http://gailbottomleyonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/facebook-schedule.jpg',
            'actions' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Google',
                    'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
                )
            )
        );
        // To authenticated user's wall
        $result     = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
    } else {
       // Do Nothing
    }
}
?>
```

The code searched for scheduled facebook posts and posts them if they match the current date and time (or are earlier than that).  But what I want to do is delete those individual scheduled posts from the database each time they are posted.

What I want to know is, where within all of this code do I post the code that will allow the scheduled post to be updated immdiately after posting it?

I hope that didn't sound too confusing because i used the word POST so many times, but I hope you get the idea.

I have tried several different ways of doing this but it doesn't delete the post from the database or simply produces errors.

So far, after testing the current code above, this part owrks fine.  The errors only come along when I try to get it to delete that post from the database by adding code to do that.

have been trying different things for the last couple of days now.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the entry from your database only if you don't get any error/exception from the facebook server; just like this:

```
try 
{
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
    // Delete the entry from database
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
{
    $result = $e->getResult();
    error_log(json_encode($result));
}
```

Comment: Well I'm still lost.  I have no idea what the facebook server will have to do with the database results from my own server.

Comment: You didnt got me. If your posting to facebook incur any error it will be caught in the catch(), just after the api call. So, simply delete your entry (which is your question), after api call. Did you tried the above code?

Comment: I tried the code but fb does not catch any errors... and the file does not get deleted.  The code I pasted gets results from my database and posts only the ones that are ready to be posted.  Then they post them just fine. No errors occurr that will cause it to be caught.

Comment: Ok. so what's the delete code you are using? Obviously your deletion code is not correct.

Comment: mysql_query("DELETE * FROM sched_posts WHERE ID='$post_id'");

right after...

$result     = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);

Comment: isd qouery giving any errors? Use instead - `if(!mysql_query){ echo mysql_error(); }`

Comment: didnt even display an error.  Just did nothing as usual and moved on.  Nevermind...  Just going to abandon and rewrite the entire page if needed... unless oyu have any other suggestions?